# How to return default values with optional partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rest, activerecord

I have a RESTful endpoint that uses the following jbuilder template:

```
json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :num_of_accounts, :platform_name
json.url tab_community_url(tab_community, format: :json)
```

Is there some way for me to have optional partials `:num_of_accounts` and `:platform_name` default to some value if the model doesn't return those values?

UPDATE: I tried adding this to my template file:

```
if tab_community.num_of_accounts.nil?
  json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at, num_of_accounts: 0, platform_name: 'Twitter'
else
  json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :num_of_accounts, :platform_name
end
json.url tab_community_url(tab_community, format: :json)
```

And here's my Rails server error msg:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `num_of_accounts' for #<TabCommunity:0x0000000be66f08>):
    1: if tab_community.num_of_accounts.nil?
    2:   json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at, num_of_accounts: 0, platform_name: 'Twitter'
    3: else
    4:   json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :num_of_accounts, :platform_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if/else` condition:

```
json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at
json.url tab_community_url(tab_community, format: :json)

if tab_community.num_of_accounts.present?
  json.num_of_accounts tab_community.num_of_accounts
else
  json.set! :num_of_accounts, 'Default value'
end
if tab_community.platform_name.present?
  json.platform_name tab_community.platform_name
else
  json.set! :platform_name, 'Default value'
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a 500 error: ```ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `num_of_accounts' for #<TabCommunity:0x00000008778730>):
    1: json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :num_of_accounts, :platform_name
    2: json.url tab_community_url(tab_community, format: :json)```

Comment: is `num_of_accounts` an attribue of your `TabCommunity` or a method ?

Comment: I'm using this in my `#index` controller method to get those values: ```.select('tab_communities.*, ref_platforms.name as platform_name, count(tab_community_accounts.id) AS num_of_accounts')```

Those other derived values are generated later on so that's why they're `null` when my controller returns from initially running `#create`.

Answer (score 0):

The two previous answers are very, very close. Aside from needing the conditional, I also needed to handle null methods properly, and the right way to see if AR methods exist is to use `.respond_to?`:

```
json.extract! tab_community, :id, :name, :ref_community_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at
json.url tab_community_url(tab_community, format: :json)

if tab_community.respond_to? :num_of_accounts
  json.num_of_accounts tab_community.num_of_accounts
else
  json.set! :num_of_accounts, 0
end
if tab_community.respond_to? :platform_name
  json.platform_name tab_community.platform_name
else
  json.set! :platform_name, 'Twitter'
end
```